# Package looking for dependencies inside it's own folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg, draftjs

I have a project that is using draft-js, it was working fine until i removed some other dependency that has nothing to do with draft-js, then i got this error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\route\project\node_modules\draft-js\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js'
```

for some reason now it search for the dependency inside the draft folder instead of the root node_modules, i checked and in fact inmutable.js is installed